# Fibonacci induction problem gone wrong!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying prove the following statement but I'm having some trouble: $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}(2j-1) = F_{2n}$$

But I've come across some contradictions (which are likely due to my own fault). I've done the base base at n = 1, which checks out.

My inductive hypothesis is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}(2j-1) = F_{2k}$$

And my inductive step is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}(2j-1) = F_{2k+1}$$

From here I can get $$\sum_{j=0}^{k}(2j-1) + F_{2k+1}= F_{2k+1}$$

We can already see the problem before I substitute in the formula from the I.H.

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In  "My inductive step" the RHS should be $F_{2(k+1)}.$

Comment: First, the formula you were trying to prove is _wrong_. Instead, it should be $\sum_{j=1}^k F_{2j-1} = F_{2k}$. Moreover, the right hand side of your inductive step should be $F_{2(k+1)}$.

Comment: You are correct on both accounts, mistranslated the problem itself onto here haha, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction allows us to prove some claim for all the naturals ($n\in\mathbb{N}$).

The claim is as follows:

$${\sum_{j=0}^{n}F_{(2j-1)}=F_{2n}}$$

Consider the base case, that is when $n=1$

$${\sum_{j=0}^{1}F_1= 1 + 1 =2} \ \checkmark$$

(Assuming you define the "0"th term as the element $1$ in the Fibonacci sequence.)

Suppose the $n^{th}$ case holds, such that:

$${\sum_{j=0}^{n}F_{(2j-1)}=F_{2n}}$$

Then we want to show the $n^{th+1}$ case holds, that is:

$${\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}F_{(2j-1)}=F_{2(n+1)}=F_{2n+2}}$$

We show this as follows:

$${\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}F_{(2j-1)}={\sum_{j=0}^{n}F_{(2j-1)}\ +F_{2n+1}=F_{2n}+F_{2n+1}=F_{2n+2}}}$$

Note, the Fibonacci sequence is obtained by simply adding the $n^{th+1}$ term to the $n^{th}$ term, producing the $n^{th+2}$ term. Also note in the $n^{th+1}$ case, the $n^{th+1}$ term is extracted from the summation, allowing us to substitute the original assumption. ($n^{th}$ case)